# why the first compiles but second doesn't

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ExceptionDemo {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
                int x = 5/0;
        }finally {

            System.out.print("exception ");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ExceptionDemo {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } finally {
            System.out.print("exception ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first doesn't explicitly throw any exceptions while the second does and you're not handling it in any way (catch it or throw it further)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel No it doesn't. There is an uncatched exception.

Comment: @BackSlash: nevermind, I didn't notice that Ideone added it automatically by itself.

Comment: Read all about _checked_ and _unchecked_ exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here :

Either catch the exception you're throwing :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.print("exception ");
    }
}
```

Either make your method throw it :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } finally {
        System.out.print("exception ");
    }
}
```

But you have to handle it anyway. My own preference being catching it and handling it directly.